# Doing 1-1 matches in OSRM in R

Tags: r, open-source-routing-machine

I am trying to build a distance "matrix" from two vectors of points in a dataset using OSRM, using a set up similar to that of mapdist or gmapsdistance.

```
hs<-hs_sf%>%
  st_as_sf(crs=4326)

traveldistance<-osrmTable(
src=c(hs_sf$geometry.x),
dst = c(hs_sf$geometry.y),
measure = "duration",
osrm.profile = "car"
)
```

I am trying to find an output of 20 rows with one vector (distance) from an input of 20 rows with two vectors (POINTS from origin and destination). Instead, I am getting 20 vectors, which I take to be part of a complete matrix. Is there any way I could use OSRM to get the latter product?